# Display table row on some condition angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `tr` tag

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of list| paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ; let i=index " *ngIf="data.status=='1'" >
<td>

</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to display `tr` only when `*ngIf="data.status=='1'"`

but getting this error

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one
> attribute prefixed with *

Any Solution Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Wrap within `<ng-container>`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of list | paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ; let i = index">
  <tr *ngIf="data.status == '1'">
    ...
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

---

**Solution 2**: Perform the filtering in the component

```js
this.list = this.list.filter((x) => x.status == '1');
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of list | paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ; let i = index">
  ...
</tr>
```

[Demo Solution 1 & 2 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pvlipx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks but when i'm using `ng-container` pagination is not working properly it is showing 3 recods on first page then rest on next page

Comment: Are you using `data.status == '1'` for filtering purpose? For first solution, let say your list contains 4 items with 2 items of status: '1'. The pagination will include 4 items. While in Solution 2, it only paginate 2 items as the list has been filtered .

Comment: i want to show records where status is `1`  It is possible with solution 1? if it is showing 2 record then pagination should also contain 2 records

Comment: *i want to show records where status is 1 It is possible with solution 1?* Not possible, Solution 2 is what you need which filter the record and paginate according to filtered record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-template` for that: https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template

Try wrapping the whole thing in `<ng-template>` and applying the structural directive to it like this:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="data.status=='1'">
    <tr
        *ngFor="let data of list| paginate:{itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:p} ; let i=index "
    >
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```